# gltf examples documentation typo?

Tags: json, parsing, graphics, gltf

In the official gltf documentation I found this:
[image]

That table seems to be saying that the first 2 values are not affected by weight one. When I load the data of this example, all the entries are equal, so it seems that the English description is right and the table is wrong. Can anyone confirm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the confusion here.  When this example was first written, all of the joint information was identical:

```
Vertex N: 0, 1, 0, 0,
```

This matches the English description below.  But then sometime early-2020, the glTF Validator was [updated to version 2.0.0-dev.3.0](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Validator/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-dev30-january-2020), which added a host of tighter skinning validation checks, including `ACCESSOR_JOINTS_USED_ZERO_WEIGHT` as a new `warning` level message when a particular non-zero joint is called out as having zero weight.  It's not an error, but the validator flags it as a warning.

Sometime mid-year, the sample model repository had its CI upgraded to use a newer glTF Validator, and the skinning tutorial model you see here [ran afoul of the new validation warning](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Sample-Models/pull/243#issuecomment-579845841).  Those first two vertices don't place any weight on joint index 1, so don't need to call out joint 1 in this list, and the validator complained.

The model was updated to fix the validation warning, by zeroing-out the first two lines.  But it looks like the corresponding descriptions weren't correctly updated, and from your description it sounds like the tutorial's own sample data may not have been updated to match what happened to the official sample model.  Seems like a bit of cleanup on this tutorial is needed.

But the actual example works fine regardless of the second joint index on the first two lines, because there's no weight placed on them for the first two vertices.